# Examples of convex sets

Tags: general-topology

A set $K \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is called convex if for each $x,y \in K$ and for each $0 \leq \lambda \leq 1$,
$(1- \lambda)x+ \lambda y \in K$.

[image]

$$D=\{ (x_1, x_2): x_1^2+x_2^2<1 \}$$

$$D \cup \{ A \} \cup \{ B \} \Rightarrow \text{ it is convex, but it is neither closed nor open }$$

$$A=(a_1, a_2), B=(b_1, b_2)$$

$D$ is convex because either we take two inner points or we take the point $A$ with the point $B$ or an inner point with the point $A$ or $B$, the line that connects these points is in the inner of the circle or at the part that connects $A$ with $B$, right?

Also, it holds that $(0,1]$ is convex, but neither open nor closed.

To show  that it is convex , we have to show that for any $0 \leq \lambda \leq 1, x, y \in (0,1]$ we have $0< (1- \lambda) x+ \lambda y \leq 1$, right?

$1- \lambda \geq  0 \Rightarrow (1- \lambda) x \geq 0 $

$\lambda  \geq 0 \Rightarrow \lambda y \geq 0$

$\Rightarrow (1- \lambda) x+ \lambda y \geq 0$

$\lambda y \leq y \leq 1$

$(1- \lambda) x \leq 1- \lambda$

$\Rightarrow (1- \lambda) x+ \lambda y \leq 2- \lambda \leq 2$

How can we show that  $(1- \lambda) x+ \lambda y \leq 1$ ?

Also is it neither open nor closed because at the left side we have $($ and at the right $]$ ?

Answer (score 0):

You are right about why the set are neither open nor closed.
For the inequality, you have immediately
\begin{equation}
(1- \lambda) x+ \lambda y \le 1-\lambda+\lambda\le1,
\end{equation}
having used that $x,y\le1$

Comment: $x$ and $y$ are $\color{red}{ vector} $ it doesnot mean $(1- \lambda) x+ \lambda y\leq 1$

Comment: But the second part of the question was about $(0,1]$ on the real line

Comment: he isnot right $x=(x_1, x_1)$ and $y=(y_1,y_2)$ see definition of $D$

Comment: It seems to me the first part is about $D$, the second, from "Also, it holds that..." concerns $(0,1]$

Answer (score 0):

$$||(1- \lambda) x+ \lambda y||\leq ||\lambda y||+||(1-\lambda)x||=\lambda||y||+(1-\lambda)||x||< \lambda+(1-\lambda)=1$$

**Note** 
$x$ and $y$ are $\color{red}{ vectors} $. It does not mean $(1- \lambda) x+ \lambda y\leq 1$.